# Maven cxf-codegen-plugin with NTLM Authentication - fails with java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL

Tags: cxf, soap-client, cxf-client, cxf-codegen-plugin, ntlm-authentication

I'm trying to generate java code using `cxf-codegen-plugin` for a SOAP webservice that is secured over NTLM. I'm not sure how do pass on the username/pwd/domain information to maven to connect to the remote server while generating the java code. I could open the wsdl using the browser using the username/pwd/domain combination I have. However, I'm wondering how to do it via command-line by passing some extra vm args to - `mvn package`. Or is there any other plugin config that I can do which helps me to do this?